# Can't report on new field on custom object

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-field

I recently created a new object type and added a formula field for the Case Safe ID. But when I try to report on that object, the new field doesn't show up in the options for report columns. Why is this?

Comment: did you check FLS?

Comment: What is FLS? @cropredy

Comment: Field level security